# How do you decide which rows to swap for a matrix while doing gaussian elimination?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, gaussian-elimination

I'm trying to do LU factorization and for one of the examples I found online, the question is to solve the equation Ax=b with A and b as follows :
[A_and_b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3NTW.png)

In their solution for finding the upper triangular matrix (U), they started by swapping rows 1 and 4 while I started by swapping 1 and 3. This is the [solution they got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlrpx.png) and here is my solution :

\begin{bmatrix}-1&2&3&-1\\0&5&5&-1\\0&0&3&-2/5\\0&0&0&2/5\end{bmatrix}

The solution they got is the correct answer which I'm able to get if in the beginning I swap rows 1 and 4 instead of 1 and 3. However I'm confused about how they decided which row to swap. I had no particular reason for choosing to swap 1 with 3, I just chose a random row. Can someone please explain the reason behind swapping 1 with 4?

Edit : This is [my full solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYUeC.jpg) Not sure where I went wrong...

Comment: There probably isn't one. You have a lot of options when choosing how to reduce the matrix and there is rarely a reason to prefer one to another.

Comment: oh i see, so in that case both of these would be correct answers? @CyclotomicField

Comment: You should always expect the same answer no matter how you get there.

Comment: @CyclotomicField ok, I see. I just edited the post with my full solution. I'm not sure why I'm not getting the same answer as the one they got. Can you please help?

Comment: Theoretically, it doesn't really matter. Practically/computationally, sometimes we want to use the row containing the element that is largest in absolute value. You can read more about **partial pivoting** -- I think that's what it's usually called.

Comment: In fact the LU factorisation is not unique as one can choose different row pivot. The thing to take the largest one (in absolute value) here three is for numerical approximation when you do an elimination for large entries.

Comment: That makes sense @ToniMhax thanks!

Comment: @twosigma I just read about pivoting, that helps with this question! thanks!